# Will Google's In App Purchase still work if I distribute my app to other app stores

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Currently, I had published my free app, with Google in app purchase to Google Play store. It works well so far.

I was wondering, if I distribute the same APK, to other app stores like Amazon, Opera, will the Google in-app purchase flow still workable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the in-app billing [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html)

```
In-app Billing can be implemented only in applications that you publish through Google Play.
```

so it looks like no it will not work